# Files getting erased whenever i run deployment

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

whenever i run a new deployment on heroku, all already uploaded files will be removed, It's a Django application which i deployed on heroku through my github repository, please how can i stop this from happening?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to explain what exactly you're doing to deploy. Normally, when updating your code, nothing changes. One thing perhaps: Where is your MEDIA_ROOT? It **must be outside of your source directory**. i.e. if /path/to/project/ contains your repository (the manage.py file is inside the project/ directory) then your MEDIA_ROOT must be above project/, i.e. in /path/ or path/to/ but not inside project/.

Comment: Hmm, i think this is where the problem lies, i have my repository inside my project folder and MEDIA_ROOT is also inside the project directory, my project name is PNM, does this mean i have to make the MEDIA_ROOT outside PNM folder?

Comment: Yes of course. It can be anywhere on your drive as long as it's not inside your git repository. But I'm not entirely sure how Heroku treats a volume and whether it persists files. Heroku explicitly warns agains it (see the answer below) and has a tutorial on [how to use S3 for file storage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python).

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted), "... the filesystem on Heroku is not suitable for persistent storage of data. In cases where you need to store data we recommend using a database addon such as Postgres (for data) or a dedicated file storage service such as AWS S3 (for static files). ".